# HTML5 Canvas typewriter effect with word wrapping?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to get an animated typewriter effect on a HTML5 Canvas but I'm really struggling with Word Wrapping.

Here's my Shapes.js in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/Jamesking56/0d7df54473085b3c5394

In there, I've created a Text object which has lots of methods. One of which is called `typeText()`.

`typeText()` basically starts off the typewriting effect but it keeps on falling off the edge and I'm really struggling to find a way of fixing word wrapping.

Can anybody guide me on whats the best way to do this?

Comment: +1 for _solution with NO plugins! Standard JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas!_. I like that. But your code is poorly commented. It is not clear what parameters `typeText` method takes and what `baseObjects` actually are.

Comment: Can you please tell how are you calling `typeText`, what are the parameters that you are passing?

Comment: `baseObjects` is an array of all my objects on the canvas (for redrawing purposes).

`typeText()` is called from the Text object. So I would do `var text = new Text();` then call `text.typeText(baseObjects, 20);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution I have used is roughly:

```
var maxWidth = 250;
var text = 'lorem ipsum dolor et sit amet...';

var words = text.split(' ');
var line = [words[0]]; //begin with a single word

for(var i=1; i<words.length; i++){
    while(ctx.measureText(line.join(' ')) < maxWidth && i<words.length-1){
        line.push(words[i++]);
    }
    if(i < words.length-1) { //Loop ended because line became too wide
        line.pop(); //Remove last word
        i--; //Take one step back
    }
    //Ouput the line
}
```

Since there seems to be no way to measure the height of the output text, you need to manually offset each line you output by some hardcoded line height.

Comment: Oh I see, you can calculate the words beforehand THEN start typing it out. Only downside is that I'm also looking for responsivity, so what would happen if a user resized my canvas?

Comment: This is the easiest solution of seen so far though and I could integrate this into my `Text` object.

Comment: @Jamesking56 You can't add the type-writing effect using this method.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I am not criticizing. I am just telling that this code fails to fulfill one of the two requirements of the OP. There's nothing wrong with your code. But, you just can't use it with the type-writer effect. If you think it can be, then I'd like to see a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how your `Text` constructor works. So I wrote an independent function (not belonging to any object). All you need to pass to this function is a string, the `X` and `Y` position, the line height and padding. It assumes the canvas to be assigned to a variable `canvas` and the 2d context to be assigned to variable `ctx`.

```
var canvas, ctx;
function typeOut(str, startX, startY, lineHeight, padding) {
    var cursorX = startX || 0;
    var cursorY = startY || 0;
    var lineHeight = lineHeight || 32;
    padding = padding || 10;
    var i = 0;
    $_inter = setInterval(function() {
        var w = ctx.measureText(str.charAt(i)).width;
        if(cursorX + w >= canvas.width - padding) {
            cursorX = startX;
            cursorY += lineHeight;
        }
        ctx.fillText(str.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
        i++;
        cursorX += w;
        if(i === str.length) {
            clearInterval($_inter);
        }
    }, 75);
}
```

Check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sann/KpdQa/).

**Tips**-

I was going through your code and found something link this-

```
function Rectangle(x,y,width,height,colour) {
    //properties
    this.draw = function() { //Don't assigns object methods through constructors
        ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
}
```

You shouldn't add methods to an object through the constructor as it creates the method every time the object is instantiated. Rather add methods to object's prototype, this way, they will be created only once and will be shared by all the instances. Like-

```
function Rectangle(x,y,width,height,colour) {
    //properties
}
Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Also, I found that you are creating extra variables to point to some objects. Like -

```
var that = this;
var fadeIn = setInterval(function() {
    //code
    that.draw();
    //code
}, time);
```

You shouldn't create an extra reference to the `Text` object. Use `bind` method so that `this` will point to the `Text` object. Like-

```
var fadeIn = setInterval(function() {
    //code
    this.draw(); // <-- Check this it is `this.draw` no need for `that.draw`
    //code
}.bind(this), time);   //bind the object
```

Read more about bind [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Hope that helps.

**PS:** 75 millisecond for each character, that will be holy 800 characters per minute !!!

---

**Update** - If you want scalable graphics you should consider [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Canvas is raster-based, whereas SVG is vector-based. Which means SVG can easily be resized whereas when you resize a canvas the content of the canvas will start to pixelate and look fuzzy. [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element#Canvas_versus_Scalable_Vector_Graphics_.28SVG.29).

To resize the content of a canvas you need to repaint the whole canvas. Whenever something is drawn on a canvas, the browser draws and forgets about it. So if you want to change the size/position of the object  you'll need to clear the canvas completely and redraw the object.  In your case, you'll need to change the `ctx.font` according to the canvas's size and then update the canvas, which is going to be a really tedious task.

Comment: The only problem I have with your demo is that my canvas is resizable by the user (it matches the browser height and width at all times). What would happen if the user resized the canvas midway through?

Comment: Thanks for the coding tips, I was actually taught at University level to use `this.draw = function(){}` for my object's methods. Don't really know if theres any sort of standard for this? As for `that = this;` I didn't actually know `.bind()` existed so that will be useful.

Comment: Canvas is a forced requirement from client so I can't use SVG unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

`<canvas>` is not designed for text handling. It is much, much, more easier doing this by overlaying transparent DOM elements on the top of your `<canvas>`. This, naturally, assumes what you don't need to post-process text pixels in `<canvas>`. Otherwise you need to re-implement the whole text handling stuff in Javascript and that's kind of reinventing the wheel, because browsers can simply do it for us.

Here are more information how to perform it using CSS `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.

[Allowing the user to type text in a HTML5 Canvas game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430069/allowing-the-user-to-type-text-in-a-html5-canvas-game/13430878#13430878)

I think you should have a DOM element which has all text with transparent colour, each letter wrapped with a `<span>`. Then you just start making those `<span>`s visible by adjusting opacity. This way the letter positions would not change.

Comment: What about the Type writing effect I was looking for? How would I type out each letter individually?

Comment: Also what about responsivity? My canvas is responsive, can overlaid text be responsive too in this way?

Comment: 1) Wrap each letter in `<span>` 2) I don't see why it would not be

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I always use bitmap fonts when I need text in my canvas games. It has a couple of advantages:

1. FillText on canvas is slow. Bitmap fonts are much faster.
2. You know the width of each letter making wrapping and text alignment much easier.

You still get the benefit of selecting font color by using an cases compositing operations, and font size by dynamically adjusting the draw width height.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean and how you would use bitmap fonts?  as it stands, this is a poor answer because it doesn't go into the detail needed to actually implement it.

Comment: You're right. It should be a comment. However that amount of text does not fit in a comment. So should I not have included it? Well I think it's still very valid and *useful* information, to what can be a deceptively complex task, that's worth sharing. I guess down voting is easier.