# Parse text and store it to render in canvas (like in console) with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have some code like this:

```
// highlight text
vi.prototype.parse = function (text) {
    // some code
    this.data = data;
};
// place it on canvas
vi.prototype.render = function () {
    /* loop */
        this.ctx.clearRect(/* ... */);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.data[i].bg;
        this.ctx.fillRect(/* ... */);
        this.ctx.fillText(data[i].text, /* ... */);
        // ....
    /* end loop */
};
```

I parse and render text every time when text changed.
Everything is complicated by the fact that the line can not get into the canvas.

```
1 Some line
2 Some long line line line line line line line li
 ne line line
3 Some line
```

What is the best way to parse and store text with background and foreground colors?

I need to print text with syntax highlighting.
I have a function that parses the text and returns it in some form, for example

```
text = "var x;";
highlightedText = vi.parse (text);
console.log (highlightedText);
>> [[  {text: "var", fg: "#dd5", bg: "#000"}, 
       {text: " ", fg: "#FFF", bg: "#000"},         
       {text: "x", fg: "#5dd", bg: "#000"}, 
       {text: ";", fg: "#FFF", bg: "#000"}]];
// Displays the text in canvas
vi.render (highlightedText);
```

I think it's not a good way to store text data

Comment: Are you asking about word wrapping?  If so you can use context.measureText to decide when you need to move down to the next line.  See this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502827/html5-canvas-typewriter-effect-with-word-wrapping.  If that's not what you're asking, could you please provide more info...

Comment: No, not that. I do not know how I store data about formatting options (background, foreground colors). I added what I have now. Maybe there are more interesting ideas or perhaps be better not to use a temporary variable, and parse directly in the method `render()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not tested code, but here are my ideas:**

Keep your style definitions in your main class (vi?)

Create textSegment objects that have everything needed to draw the text:

- The text.
- The style of the text.
- The width of the text.

Keep all your textSegments in an array in your main class.

```
    this.textSegments.push({ 
        text  : text, 
        textWidth : ctx.measureText(newText).width, 
        style : style 
    });
```

Here is code (untested/incomplete!):

```
function vi(context,lineheight){

    this.ctx=context;
    this.lineHeight=lineheight;
    this.textSegments=[];
    this.x=0;
    this.y=0;

    // keep the style definitions once and reference them in your text segments
    this.styles=[];
    this.styles["normal"]=   { font:"12px Arial", bg:"#000", fg:"#fff" };
    this.styles["operator"]= { font:"12px Arial", bg:"#000", fg:"#5dd" };
    this.styles["keywordS"]= { font:"12px Arial", bg:"#000", fg:"#d55" };

}
//
// usage: myVi.addTextSegment("Hello","normal");
//
vi.prototype.addTextSegment(text,style){

    // measure the text once while you're adding it
    this.ctx.font=newStyle.font;

    // create a textSegment object 
    // that has everything needed to draw the text
    this.textSegments.push({ 
        text  : text, 
        textWidth : ctx.measureText(newText).width, 
        style : style 
    });
}
// draw the textSegment
vi.prototype.drawTextSegment(textSegment){
    var style=this.styles[textSegment.style];
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.font=textSegment.style.font;
    this.ctx.fillStyle=textSegment.style.bg;
    this.ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,textSegment.textWidth,this.lineHeight);
    this.drawText(textSegment.text,this.x,this.y);
    this.ctx.restore();
    this.x+=textSegment.textWidth;
}
```